# Laravel 4 model, controller and route error

Tags: laravel, model, controller, laravel-4

I can't get rid of the errors. I've created an model, and have functions in controllers and a route, but I get errors.

my model(newsticker.php):

```
    <?php

class Newsticker extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'aac_newsticker';

    protected $fillable = array('label', 'content');
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

my controller (also used for other functions, but used also for newstickers):

```
    <?php

class NewsController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * News Repository
     *
     * @var News
     */
    protected $news;

    public function __construct(News $news)
    {
      $this->news = $news;
    }

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  News Functions
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */

public function index()
{

 return View::make('admin.news_managment')->with('newss', $this->news->all());
}

public function create()
{

  return View::make('admin.create_news');
}

public function store()
{
  $input = Input::all();

  $rules = array(
    'author' => 'required|min:4|max:255',
    'title' => 'required|unique:aac_news,title|min:4|max:255',
    'content' => 'required|unique:aac_news,content|min:10'
    );

  $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

  if ($validation->fails()) {

   return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation);

 } else {

  News::create($input);
  return Redirect::to('news/index');
}
}

public function delete($newsId)
{
 $news = $this->news->findOrFail($newsId);
 $news->delete();
 return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Your news post has been deleted.');
}

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Newsticker Functions
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */

public function newsticker_index()
{
  return View::make('aac.index')->with('newstickers', Newsticker::all());
}

}
```

also here's my index.blade.php:

```
@extends('base')
@section('title', 'Home')
@stop 
@section('main')

@foreach($newstickers as $newsticker)
      <div class="alert alert-info"><span class="label label-info">{{ $newsticker->created_at }}</span>
        <span class="label label-success">{{ $newsticker->label }}</span>

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <td>{{ $newsticker->content }}</td>
      </div>

    </div>
@endforeach

@foreach($newss as $news)
  <div class="doc-content-box">
      <legend>{{ $news->title }} <div id="spaceholder"></div>

        <p>
          <h6><i class="icon-calendar"></i> {{ $news->created_at }} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/profile/{{ $news->author }}">{{ $news->author }}</a>
        </p>
      </h6>
      </legend>

  <div style="margin-top:7px">

<p>{{ $news->content }}</p>

@if (Auth::check())

                    @if ($roles == 5)

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>

    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ URL::action('NewsController@delete', ['id' => $news->id]) }}"><i class="icon-trash icon-large"></i> Delete</a>
  </div>

                        @endif

                        @endif

  </div>
</div>
@endforeach

@stop
```

and my route:

```
    # News ticker
Route::get('admin/dash/newsticker', 'NewsController@newsticker_index');
```

I want to display it on my index page( / or news/index), but I've set it to admin/dash/newsticker. I've also tried changing it to / or news/index but I get an error in the laravel's php server and a blank page.

```
    [Sun Aug 04 18:12:23 2013] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionExcep
tion' with message 'Class NotAllowedHttpException does not exist' in C:\Users\E1
\Desktop\l4\bootstrap\compiled.php:7543
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\E1\Desktop\l4\bootstrap\compiled.php(7543): ReflectionParameter->get
Class()
#1 C:\Users\E1\Desktop\l4\bootstrap\compiled.php(7537): Illuminate\Exception\Han
dler->hints(Object(ReflectionFunction), Object(ReflectionException))
#2 C:\Users\E1\Desktop\l4\bootstrap\compiled.php(7512): Illuminate\Exception\Han
dler->handlesException(Object(Closure), Object(ReflectionException))
#3 C:\Users\E1\Desktop\l4\bootstrap\compiled.php(7481): Illuminate\Exception\Han
dler->callCustomHandlers(Object(ReflectionException))
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleException(Object(Ref
lectionException))
#5 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\E1\Desktop\l4\bootstrap\compiled.php on line 7543
```

Comment: I think you are missing call to parent constructor

Comment: @Trying Tobemyself huh, could you clarify?

Comment: you can view the code on github if you need to.. https://github.com/larryfour/emiAAC

Comment: I mean you are missing `parent::__construct()` call in your `NewsController constructor`

Comment: Route should be: Route::get('admin/dash/newsticker', 'NewsController@index'); and there's a typo when you pass data to your view in the index function: ->with('newss', $this->news->all());